# Boost Graph Library, stable on iOS?

Tags: ios, boost, boost-graph

> The Boost Graph Library is a header-only library and does not need to be built to be used.

it contains some pre-made functions that I want for my iOS application:

- `dijkstra_shortest_paths`
- `astar_search`

However, Boost is **not officially supported on iOS** (or Android) due to lack of regression testing, and I'm not experienced enough with either Boost or iOS to be comfortable testing it.

Is anyone using `Boost.Graph` on iOS, and if so is it stable?

Comment: Absolutely it's stable. C++(11!) is fully implemented on iOS, and it's allowed by the developer agreements put forth by apple. Boost is an awesome library, use it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most definitely it's stable.

Apple's LLVM compiler (which is what you should be using for iOS apps) is one of the most C++11 compliant compilers available today, and as such can compile and run boost with absolutely no issues.

Not to mention the fact that iOS is also fully POSIX compliant, which makes most frameworks out there viable for use on iOS. When in doubt, try it and then if it *doesn't* work, come back and ask a question.

Leverage what is already there, and use it well!

Comment: I don't think that's true. A quick inspection of the [Boost Regression Tests](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/release/developer/summary.html) page reveals **nothing can compile and run boost** with absolutely no issues. Concerning also is that not even `Sandia-darwin-clang-trunk-c++11` can compile all of `Boost.Graph`.

Answer (score 0):

As such boost libraries are stable, but Boost Graph libraries are failing on all darwin flavours (darwin- 4.4_0x    intel- darwin- 12.0 intel- darwin- 11.1 darwin- 4.4)

http://www.boost.org/development/tests/release/developer/summary.html

May be you can try other alternatives, like LEDA (http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/news/archive.htm)

Thanks.

Comment: The current version of that table shows it working just fine on Clang.